# Automatic inclusion of @2x images (retina support)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiimage

Can any one tell me code of auto including @2x images if device is switched to iphone 4.
I have searched very far on it, but nothing fruitful is found yet.

I have already included @2x images in my resource file. I want code to write so that images resize and reposition them selves when application is running on iphone 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just include the @2x with the normal image in your project, the os will get the @2x if needed.

When you refer to an image always refer to the non-@2x image and iOS will get the @2x image on iphone 4 (or ipod) if you take it in your project and add to the target of course.

Comment: I am fully satisfied with your solution. Thanks. But I wanted to ask that if I have choosed pre-decided scale for my UIImage at interface, like self.imageViewLogo.frame = CGRectMake(123, 205, 250, 66); then how it can be scale to @2x images.... Please let me clear on that or provide any better suggestion for the same.

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "auto-including" ?

If you have `fooBar.png` and `fooBar@2x.png` in your project resource, then when you do :

```
UIImage * fooBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fooBar.png"];
```

It will automatically load `fooBar.png` if your screen scale is 1.0 (iPhone3G/3GS) or `fooBar@2x.png` if your screen scale is 2.0 (retina, iPhone 4).

cf [UIImage#imageNamed](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageNamed%3a)